# How to specialize type of discriminated union?

Tags: typescript

Assume I have two discriminated unions and a third type alias which is a union type containing both.

How do I create a function which can take both the discriminated unions but whose return type depends on the specific type of the value passed?

I thought this would work, given that `Specialize` would return `{ value: number }` if the passed value belongs to `First` and `number` if it belongs to `Second`, but it doesn't.

```js
type First = "a" | "b";
type Second = "c" | "d";
type Letter = First | Second;
type Specialize<R> = R extends First ? { value: number } : number;

const fun = <M extends Letter, R extends Specialize<M>>(letter: M): R => {
    return letter === "a" || letter === "b"
        ? { value: 1 }
        : 2;
}
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

Please notice that I *do not* want to remove the `R` which constrains the return type. Instead, I'd like to constrain the return type to the passed argument.

---

```
Type '{ value: number; } | 2' is not assignable to type 'R'.
  '{ value: number; } | 2' is assignable to the constraint of type 'R', but 'R' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number | { value: number; }'.
    Type '{ value: number; }' is not assignable to type 'R'.
      '{ value: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'R', but 'R' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number | { value: number; }'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for overloads. By providing specific overloads for narrowed cases, the return value will also be narrowed.

```
// Overloads
function fun(letter: First): { value: number };
function fun(letter: Second): number;
// General case
function fun(letter: Letter): { value: number } | number {
    return letter === "a" || letter === "b"
        ? { value: 1 }
        : 2;
}

const x = fun("a")   // x: { value: number }
const y = fun("c")   // y: number
```

Your generics-based approach can't work because the caller gets to decide what `R` is, and `R` can be *any* type that extends `Specialize<M>`. That's what the errors are telling you. You have no way to return the specific subtype the caller has chosen.

(Given TypeScript's structural typing, I'm not aware of particular way to create a subtype of `Specialize<R>`. But the compiler can't prove that it's impossible, and I'm sure someone more clever with TypeScript than I am can think of one. But by using `extends` you specifically said that the caller can require a subtype, and that makes returning `R` impossible.)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the polymorphism given by the generic constraint.

Defining your function as generic with an argument type which extends from another, you must ensure your `return` statement actually returns a value which is assignable of type `T` and its extensions (where `T` is the type argument).

Let's suppose you define this type

```
type MoreSpecialize<R> = R extends First ? { value: 10 } : 20;
```

... which extends from `Specialize<>`. I could invoke the function `fun` with this type argument,

```
const r: MoreSpecialize<Letter> = fun2<Letter, MoreSpecialize<Letter>>('a');
```

But, `r` is not actually of type `MoreSpecialize<Letter>` because `fun` returns `{ value: 1 } | 2`, not `{ value: 10 } | 20`. That's why the compiler complains.

#### Solution

1. Define your function with concrete types if you are not going to need extensions, indeed.

```
const fun = (letter: Letter): Specialize<Letter> => {
    return letter === "a" || letter === "b"
        ? { value: 1 }
        : 2;
}
```

2. Force casting the return value [!].
   Not the best way to go.

```
const fun2 = <M extends Letter, R extends Specialize<M>>(letter: M): R => {
    return (
        letter === "a" || letter === "b"
            ? { value: 1 }
            : 2
    ) as R;
}
```

3. @RobNapier's solution is totally fine.

Hope it helps.